# Archaic English new words: from a Nigerian

Tags: single-word-requests, british-english, early-modern-english

A Nigerian Governor was being interviewed by a local Television station.
He was speaking of the political situation of Rivers state in Nigeria. Nigeria is an English speaking country because it was a British Colony. However , I hardly got any word from the Governor . I only got a few words like odoriferous, political crinkum crunkum , political higi haga, transmogrified, cue gargatuagaga!!!

Is anyone understanding these words, where could be the possible source for his words. 
. Am Kenyan and my English is pretty good.

Please listen:

http://youtu.be/I1bt-GyxiYI

Comment: It's usually [**crinkum-crankum**](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/crinkum-crankum) *(a fanciful name for any object that is full of twists and turns)*. Apparently, [**higi-haga**](http://www.nairaland.com/1378181/text-meaning-patrick-obahiagbons-discussion) (previously unknown to me) means much the same. The usages in what seems to be the specific text you're referring to [are discussed in some detail here](http://www.nairaland.com/1378181/text-meaning-patrick-obahiagbons-discussion) *(Text And Meaning Of Patrick Obahiagbon's Discussion On Rivers Crisis)*.

Comment: I can understand most of it... It's not so much archaic as it's likely regional and I don't think his accent helps... his manner of speaking, with so many pauses, is certainly interesting but it helps give your brain a little bit of time to think about what he's just said. The beginning of what he says sounds like a lot of buzzwords but if you get a bit into it, it gets a bit more normal. Regardless, I'm not sure what you're asking **us** to do for you. We're not really transcribers.

Comment: It most certainly isn't BBC English - but may well be intelligible to Nigerians.

Comment: Why was this voted down?  The OP didn't ask the site to transcribe for him (although someone was interested enough to do so.)  He asked for a source and a clue.  If all posters did complete research on their questions, the site would disappear.  Moreover, I think we should be grateful to the OP for bringing this gorgeous speech to our attention.  Read it!

Answer (score 1):

I found a (very rough) transcription of this here:

https://tokunboajewole.wordpress.com/2013/07/29/rivers-crisis-these-issues-are-bringing-calamitous-end-for-nigeria-obahiagbo-pt1-transcribed/

I have not edited it at all, which means that any grammar or spelling issues have been kept. I have a feeling this isn't a very good transcription, but it's decent.

> @0.15 Let me say Prestissimo, that is as quickly as possible, that the political crim crum cram crum, or if you like, the political higi haga that has enveloped the politics of Rivers state for a period of eye-on-now, has all the trappings of an odoriferous-saga, cum, gargantuan-gaga; and I am maniacally bewildered that this flashpuent is of no serious concern to the commander in chief of the federal republic of Nigeria. This is because, all the flashpuence of war that has snowballed and transmogrified into bringing about a calamitous end for Nigeria always had always had their terminus a quo, their source of origin datis either in one state or in one region.
>
> For me, as far as I am concerned, I can see the ship of the Nigerian state hovering around the political bermuda triangle, and if we do not take very urgent and responsible steps to meander the interstices of eschewable cataracts, landmines, waterfronts, icebergs and oxbow-lakes, the ship of the Nigerian state just now has all the capacities and possibliities of berthing in a disastrous and pestilencial acqua of a terminus a quem.
>
> Let me say, let me say that my critical history and historigraphy of the study of the war of attrition and belligerency in Rivers state did not commence with the obi…??? political tendency. It commenced strictly speaking with the suspicion by some power centers that governor Rotimi Amaechi nurses an ambition for the vice presidency of this country.
>
> @2.55 Oh, its very crystal clear like the Biblical teke teke mene upharsin, it is audible to the deaf and visible to the blind, and any case, no less a political personage than the President of the Federal Republic of Nigeria, President Jonathan has been aired to have confirmed that.
>
> We read that in the papers that 2015 is the fons et origo of this crisis, is the fons et origo of the political tension in the country, and he urged political dramatis personnel to put their ships in their sur????, that 2015 is still faraway. But if you at the totality, the totality of the crisis in Rivers state just now, it leaves me with just two conclusions:
>
> 1) that 2015 is innately laden with a political and democratic thalidomide;…it may be stillborn 2) whereby some socio-scientists have gone to town for donkey-years now saying that what we have now is not a democracy but what we have is civilian rule; but by recent events, im even tempted to say that,no, no, no, no, no, no; Nigeria is neither witnessing civilian rule nor is Nigeria witnessing even democracy. What we have at best is a form of government I call cakistomobo-plutocracy. And that is bad for the nation. Is it within the obi-o-pok?????-context, or is it within the NGF election context where 16-persons are more than 19-persons. If within the microscopic ceramics and cadence of 36-governors who are supposed to be suzerains of democratic ethics and ethos in their respective terra firmas, you cannot adjudge democratic scores…….

Comment: So, he's a pompous windbag. I've certainly heard Americans who speak this way too -- usually small-town mayors.

Comment: I would very much would like to have a piece of such speeches @Ernest

Comment: http://nyack-ny.gov/mayor-laird-whites-acceptance-speech/ Here is a suitably pompous speech